# NodeJS: Where does console.debug output go?

Tags: node.js

Where does console.debug output go? And how can it be enabled to appear on the stdout, like console.log?

I looked it up in https://nodejs.org/api/console.html, but it does not appear.
If, however, I run node from the command line, it is defined.

```
node
console.debug
[Function: debug]
console.debug('but where does this go?')
```

So the function is defined, but (by default) doesn't output to stdout or stderr.  I'm guessing there is a flag to enable to turn it on.

Comment: i'd guess you'd be able to see them if you were using the debugger, but i've never messed with it.

Comment: Yeah, just tested, those ARE visible in the debugger. @23k

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Starting with node v8.0.0 and prior to v8.10 and v10.x (depending on the specific method), the global `console` exposed many of the same methods that are exposed in browsers, but did not document their existence or behavior.  Such methods include:

```
console.debug                 console.dirxml                console.markTimeline
console.profile               console.profileEnd            console.table
console.timeStamp             console.timeline              console.timelineEnd
```

The implementation for these methods were not in node (they did not appear in [lib/console.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/console.js)); they were added by V8 itself and were [copied](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v8.9.0/lib/internal/bootstrap_node.js#L331-L351) onto node's global `console` object.

As you've observed, calling these methods did not result in anything going to stdout.  Instead, **output goes to any attached inspectors**.

This means you have to run node with the `--inspect` flag, open Chrome and go to `chrome://inspect`, then attach the inspector to your process.  You will see the output of the extended console methods in the *inspector's* console.

Keep in mind that by default, the inspector console filters out calls to `console.debug`.  You need to click the **levels** dropdown and check **Verbose** in order to see `console.debug` output.

Alternatively, you could:

- In node v8.0-8.9, do something like `console.debug = console.log` if you just want to see output on stdout
- update to node v8.10

---

As of [v8.10.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V8.md#2018-03-06-version-8100-carbon-lts-gibfahn), the `console.debug` method is implemented by node and its output appears on stdout.  The GUI inspector retains its behavior (messages are hidden unless you change the logging level).

node [v10.x](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V10.md) implements many of the other methods listed above, which means these methods are now work as expected (ie show up on stdout) and are [documented](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html).